# No Database Connection: MariaDB Won't Start

Tags: mariadb, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

When I run the command `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart`, my Apache server starts but MariaDB does not. Below are the logs from `journalctl -xe`.

```
Aug 16 16:29:54 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: ## 2022-08-16 16:29:54+00:00 ## INFO ## Starting services...
Aug 16 16:29:55 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: 2022-08-16T16:29:55.550Z - info: Saving configuration info to disk
Aug 16 16:29:55 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: 2022-08-16T16:29:55.915Z - info: Performing service start operation for php
Aug 16 16:29:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: php 16:29:56.22 INFO  ==> php-fpm is already running
Aug 16 16:29:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: 2022-08-16T16:29:56.225Z - info: Performing service start operation for apache
Aug 16 16:29:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: apache 16:29:56.50 INFO  ==> apache is already running
Aug 16 16:29:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: 2022-08-16T16:29:56.503Z - info: Skipping service start operation for varnish
Aug 16 16:29:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: 2022-08-16T16:29:56.503Z - info: Performing service start operation for mariadb
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: mariadb 16:30:56.82 ERROR ==> mariadb did not start
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: 2022-08-16T16:30:56.831Z - error: Unable to perform start operation Export start for mariadb failed with exit code 1
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: ## 2022-08-16 16:30:56+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/010_bitnami_agent_extra...
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: ## 2022-08-16 16:30:56+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/020_bitnami_agent...
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: ## 2022-08-16 16:30:56+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/030_update_welcome_file...
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: ## 2022-08-16 16:30:56+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/040_bitnami_credentials_file...
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 bitnami[7264]: ## 2022-08-16 16:30:56+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/050_clean_metadata...
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 sudo[7255]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 16 16:30:56 ip-172-26-6-254 systemd[1]: bitnami.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit bitnami.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
```

When I try restarting just MariaDB (`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart mariadb`), the command hangs for about 1 minute and then I get the following (unhelpful) error:

`Failed to restart mariadb: Failed to restart mariadb`

I'm not sure what else to do here.

Comment: I removed the 'mysql' tag because you say you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed progressively since then. Although they still have some code in common, we should not consider MariaDB and MySQL as compatible products anymore.

Comment: Voting to migrate this question to dba.stackexchange.com. Stack Overflow is for questions about specific code problems, not general troubleshooting about starting db services.

Comment: That said, you can start troubleshooting by looking into the [MariaDB Server error log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/error-log/). Look first for lines with the word "ERROR".